# Detect symbols that are not enclosed within double quotes (regex)

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to design a regex that can mmatch the characters `[].\,();~-` that are **not** enclosed within double quotes.

For example, this string:

```
do Output.printString("Test 1: expected result: 5; actual result: ");
```

should return matches:

```
['.', '(', ')', ';']
```

I tried using negative lookahead and negative lookbehind to no avail.

Comment: What if it's an escaped string sequence, e.g. `do Output.printString("Test 1: expected result: 5; \"(actual)\" result: ");` ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible in Python's regexp alone.

Comment: Why should `;` be returned since it is found in the test string?

Comment: @zwer didn't think that far but any symbols within the outermost double quotes shouldn't be matched

Comment: Find all quoted text and remove them then operate on this modified string.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness: Because it's found outside quotes (last character in the line).

Comment: @marekful i was thinking that, but is there any better solution that can do both operations at once?

Comment: actually you could use my answer by adding extra check that after first occurrence of " don't add to list until next "; it should be fine not giving full solution, but you even did not think just down-vote in a second :( - it actually work like that just add this one condition yourself - but I deleted my answer

Comment: @Drako: It was a bad answer. Should you change it to actually work (and undelete it), I will be happy to turn the downvote upside down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex with a lookahead that makes sure to match a symbol outside pair of double quotes:

```
>>> s = 'do Output.printString("Test 1: expected result: 5; actual result: ");'
>>> print re.findall(r'[][.,();~-](?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)', s)
['.', '(', ')', ';']
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HbZDmj/1)

- This regex will split on given special characters if those are outside double quotes by using a lookahead to make sure there are even number of quotes after matched character.
- `(?:[^"]*"){2}` finds a pair of quotes
- `(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*` finds 0 or more such pairs
- `[^"]*$` makes sure that we don't have any more quotes after last matched quote

Answer (score 1):

You need two steps, as Python regular expressions are not powerful enough to do it in one go.

```
re.findall(r'[\[\].\\,();~-]', re.sub(r'"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"', '', s))
# => ['.', '(', ')', ';']
```

The inner `re.sub` deletes all double-quoted strings (ignoring escaped double quotes); then you can use `re.findall` to easily pick up what you want.

Comment: @marekful: Haha, I was halfway through my answer when you commented, but sure :)

Comment: No worries! I wasn't going to post an answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

We could do something like -

**Remove text inside double quotes**

```
import re
pattern = u"[\"].*?[\"]"
text = 'do Output.printString("Test 1: expected result: 5; actual result: ");'
new_text = re.sub(ptrn, '', text)
# O/P 'do Output.printString();'
```

**Match all characters you need**

```
pattern_2 = u"[\[\]\.\,\(\)\;\~\-]"
matches = re.findall(pattern2, new_text)
```

**O/P** `['.', '(', ')', ';']`